# How to find the 4 number sum given an array with no duplicate values and a target sum?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to find four number sum for a given array. The task is to find all quadruplets in the array that sum up to the target sum and return a two-dimensional array of all these quadruplets in no particular order. If no four unique numbers sum up to the target sum, the function should return an empty array.

I tried following code seems to work fine but I get one additional quadruple because of duplicate element.

```
  function fourSum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],10) {
    var hash = {};
    var quadruples = [];
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<array.length;j++){
            var Q = 0;
            var P = 0;
            if(i<j){
                Q = array[i]+array[j];

          if(hash[(targetSum - Q)]){
                    for(var k=0; k< hash[(targetSum - Q)].length; k++){
                        var combination = [hash[(targetSum - Q)][k][0] , hash[(targetSum - Q)][k][1] ,array[i], array[j]];
                        quadruples.push(combination);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(i>j){
                P = array[i]+array[j];
                if(hash[P]){
                    hash[P].push([array[i], array[j]]);
                }else{
                    hash[P] = [[array[i], array[j]]];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return quadruples;
  }
```

This returns me following: {[2, 1, 2, 5], [2, 1, 3, 4]} which is incorrect because in [2, 1, 2, 5], we have 2 two time. I am unable to find out where I am wrong in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use a recursive approach and visit all indices only once but store either the element or not and call the funtion again.

This approach has two parts, on function for preparing the result set and make an initial call of the recursive function `iter`. Tha call starts with index zero, an empty temporary array for collecting items and zero as accumulates sum of the `temp` array.

The function `iter` has two parts,

1. for exit conditions, like

   - check if `temp` has the wanted length, then check `total` with the wanted sum and take `temp` as part result. Exit the function/recursion.
   - check if `total` is greater then the `sum` (this is a short circuit if all numbers are positive) or if `index` is is not value, then exit the function/recursion.
2. for calling the `iter` again

   - with new values, like add item and value to `total`,
   - without new values, just increment the index.

```js
function subSetSum(array, sum, length) {
    function iter(index, temp, total) {
        if (temp.length === length) {
            if (total === sum) result.push(temp);
            return;
        }
        if (total > sum || index >= array.length) return;
        iter(index + 1, [...temp, array[index]], total + array[index]);
        iter(index + 1, temp, total);
    }

    var result = []
    iter(0, [], 0);
    return result;
}

console.log(subSetSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 10, 4)); // only a single array
console.log(subSetSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 15, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can divide this task into 2 actions:

- We could find all combinations of a given array
- Find first combination which satisfy condition

So the first action can be done using recursive approach. This code is based on [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880094/given-an-array-how-to-generate-all-combinations-of-subset-size-k):

```
let allCombinations = [];
const getAllCombinations = (set, k, partial) => {
    if (!partial) partial = [];
    for (var element in set) {
        if (k > 1) {
            var set_copy = set.slice();
            set_copy.splice(element, 1);
            getAllCombinations(set_copy, k - 1, partial.concat([set[element]]));
        }
        else {
            allCombinations.push(partial.concat([set[element]]));
        }
    }
}
```

The second action is to find array which satisfy desired condition:

```
const findCombination = (arr, desiredSum) => {
    const sum = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
        a+=c;
        return a;
    }, 0);

    if (sum == desiredSum)
        return arr;

    return false;
}
```

An example:

```js
const getSubsetSum = (arr, sum, length) => {

    let allCombinations = [];
    const getAllCombinations = (set, k, partial) => {
        if (!partial) partial = [];
        for (var element in set) {
            if (k > 1) {
                var set_copy = set.slice();
                set_copy.splice(element, 1);
                getAllCombinations(set_copy, k - 1, partial.concat([set[element]]));
            }
            else {
                allCombinations.push(partial.concat([set[element]]));
            }
        }
    }

    getAllCombinations(arr, length);

    const findCombination = (arr, desiredSum) => {
        const sum = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
            a+=c;
            return a;
        }, 0);

        if (sum == desiredSum)
            return arr;

        return false;
    }

    return allCombinations.find(s => findCombination(s, sum));
}
console.log(getSubsetSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 10, 4));
console.log(getSubsetSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 15, 4));
```